# SQL BigQuery: How to populate dates from rows cycle_base and cycle_interval

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm having trouble populating dates with variable **cycle_base** (day of week) and **cycle_interval** (days) columns in Google BigQuery SQL.

The idea is to populate a date array for 2022 for each **product** where the dates fall within the **valid_from** and **valid_to** dates and where the dates are generated with the respective **cycle_interval**

A snippet from my data looks like this:

| cycle_base | valid_from | valid_to | cycle_interval | product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-09-19 | 2020-04-20 | 2022-12-31 | 7 | A |
| 2018-12-17 | 2020-01-27 | 2022-12-31 | 28 | B |
| 2019-12-30 | 2020-01-27 | 2022-12-31 | 56 | C |

I tried generating a date array and then joining those dates on the DAYOFWEEK, which ofcourse only works for rows with a interval of 7 days. But I can't seem to find a way to achieve the above with the other intervals.

**Edit**
Expected data for 2022:

The cycle_base represents the day of the week. The exact date is irrelevant really. **Edit**: The date represents the starting point from which to interval the weeks.

Product A starts on monday for every week.
Product B starts on monday for every 3 weeks.
Product C starts on monday for every 8 weeks.

| date | product | dayofweek | cycle_interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-03 | A | monday | 7 |
| 2022-01-10 | A | monday | 7 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-03 | B | monday | 28 |
| 2022-01-17 | B | monday | 28 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-01-03 | C | monday | 56 |
| 2022-02-21 | C | monday | 56 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Hope someone can point me in the right direction :)

Thanks in advance,

Glenn

Comment: Can you provide your expected data as well?

Comment: not clear the role/use of `cycle_base` - please explain more and also provide sample of expected output (based on presented input)

Comment: Hi Ricco and Mikhail, I edited the post with the expected data :)